# Having problems with making explosions on Canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html, html5-canvas

I am new here and a student in an informatics degree program. I am having trouble with some parts of one of my projects due next week. We were asked to do a project that contained all of these requirements.

1. fullscreen and webapp enabled
2. touch and mouse events
3. appropriately use arrays and functions
4. use event locations (pageX & pageY) to impact the x and y behavior of your canvas elements
5. must continually generate visuals -- no 'end of animation' permitted

So i chose to do some sort of fireworks show in which a certain amount of generated balls of different sizes were going to come in from the bottom of the canvas page and fly up towards around 1/3 from the top then they would get spliced out and an explosion would go on at the same time. While the circle would explode a new one would be generated at the bottom of the canvas and it would continue and so forth.

So i need help doing the explosion(creating tiny circles that shoot away from the center of the circle which disappear(exploded)) when they get to 1/3 of the top as well as adding mouse events / touch events to prematurely make the circles explode. Any help would be great thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

        <title>basic_canvas</title>
        <style>
            #mycanvas {
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: black;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            //global variables
            var mycanvas;
            var ctx;

            //make an array of balls shooting from the bottom of the page to the middle of the page

            var Balls = [];
            var fireworks = [];

            //make a ready handler for our page to tirgger my javascript
            $(document).ready(function () {

                mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
//                mycanvas = $('#mycanvas');
                ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

                mycanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                mycanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                setInterval(draw, 33);

                //make the balls here
                for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    Balls[i] = new Ball(getRandomFloat(0, mycanvas.width), mycanvas.height, getRandomFloat(20, 70), getRandomFloat(0.1, 1));
                }
                // event listeners here

            });
            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
                for (var i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++) {
                    Balls[i].makeCirc();
                    Balls[i].moveCirc();

                }
            }

            function degToRad(deg) {
                radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
                return radians;
            }
            function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
                return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            }
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }

            //make my flying balls here
            //ball(x start value, y start value, radius, speed)
            function Ball(xin, yin, radin, spin) {
                //make all the variables for the Ball

                var x = xin;
                var y = yin;
                var r = radin;
                var sp = spin;

                //generating random colors for the circles
                var c = 'rgb(' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ',' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ',' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ')';
                //draw the circle
                this.makeCirc = function () {
                    ctx.fillStyle = c;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                this.moveCirc = function () {
                    y -= sp;

                    if (y + r < mycanvas.height / 3) {

//                        fireworks[fireworks.length] = new Fireworks(x,y,2);
                        Balls.splice(Balls.indexOf(this), 1);
                    }
                }
            }

//            function Firework(xin,yin,rin){
//                var x = xin;
//                var y = yin;
//                var r = rin;
//                
//            }


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explosion = create new circles?

Comment: Yea create a bunch of tiny circles that explode away from the point in which the bigger circle exploded and disappeared from

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to fix my project. Just in case someone else ever needs something similar i am posting the fixed code.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

        <title>Balloon_Fireworks</title>
        <style>
            #mycanvas {
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: black;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0
            }

            #score_card {

                position:absolute;
                top:25px;
                left:25px;
                padding-top:25px;
                padding-left:25px;
                width:100px;
                height:75px;
                background-color: rgb(112,200,112);
                color:rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
                font-size:50px;
                font-family: sans-serif;  
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            //global variables
            var mycanvas;
            var ctx;

            //make an array of balls shooting from the bottom of the page to the middle of the page

            var Balls = [];
            var Fireworks = [];

            //global keep track of where i click
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;

            //Counts the number of fireworks popped
            var point_counter = 0;


            //make a ready handler for our page to tirgger my javascript
            $(document).ready(function () {

                mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
//                mycanvas = $('#mycanvas');
                ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

                mycanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                mycanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                mycanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', explodeThis);
                mycanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', explodeThis);

                setInterval(draw, 33);

                //make the balls here

                //new Ball( x, y, rad, speedx, speedy);
                for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    Balls[i] = new Ball(getRandomFloat(0, mycanvas.width), mycanvas.height, getRandomFloat(50, 70), getRandomFloat(-3, -1));
                }
                // event listeners here

            });
            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
                for (var i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++) {
                    Balls[i].makeCirc();
                    Balls[i].moveCirc();
                }

                for (var i = 0; i< Fireworks.length; i++){
                    Fireworks[i].drawFire();
                    Fireworks[i].moveFire();
                }
            }

            function explodeThis(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                mouseX = e.pageX || e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
                mouseY = e.pageY || e.targetTouches[0].pageY;

                for (var i = 0; i< Balls.length; i++){
                    Balls[i].hit();
                }
            }

            function degToRad(deg) {
                radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
                return radians;
            }
            function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
                return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            }
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }

            //make my flying balls here
            //ball(x start value, y start value, radius, speed)
            function Ball(xin, yin, radin, spyin, spxin, cin){
                //make all the variables for the Ball

                var x = xin;
                var y = yin;
                var r = radin;
                var spy = spyin;
                var spx = spxin || 0;

                //make a gravity for me
                var g = getRandomFloat(.0001,.05);

                //generating random colors for the circles
                var c = cin || 'rgb(' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ',' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ',' +
                        getRandomInt(0, 255) +
                        ')';
                //draw the circle
                this.makeCirc = function () {
                    ctx.fillStyle = c;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.fill();
                };

                this.moveCirc = function () {
                    y += spy;
                    x += spx;
                    // At 1/3 from the top the balls will explode
                    if (y+r < mycanvas.height/3) { 
                    }
                };

                this.gravityMe = function () {
                    spy += g;
                };

                this.hit = function () {
                    var d = Math.sqrt( (x-mouseX)*(x-mouseX) + (y-mouseY)*(y-mouseY) );
                    if (d < r){
                        //when it hits


                        spy = 0;

                        //make a new set of fireworks using the last place
                        Fireworks[Fireworks.length] = new Firework (x, y, r, c);
                        //access that last one you just made, and add in particles
                        Fireworks[Fireworks.length-1].makeFire();
                        c = 'rgba(255,255,255,0)';
                        r = 0;

                        point_counter ++;
//                        console.log(point_counter);
                        document.getElementById('score_card').innerHTML = point_counter;

                        //make a new one
                        Balls[Balls.length] = new Ball(getRandomFloat(0, mycanvas.width), mycanvas.height+70, getRandomFloat(50, 70), getRandomFloat(-5, -2));
                    }
                };

            }
            // make the circles that explode out
            //firework(x value, y value, radius)
            function Firework(xin,yin,rin, cin){
                var x = xin;
                var y = yin;
                var r = rin;
                var color = cin;

                //make an array
                var particles = new Array(getRandomInt(10,30));

                this.makeFire = function () {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
                        particles[i] = new Ball(getRandomFloat(x-r,x+r), getRandomFloat(y-r, y+r), getRandomInt(2,10), getRandomFloat(-1,1), getRandomFloat(-3, 3), color);
                    }
                };

                this.drawFire = function () {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
                        particles[i].makeCirc();
                    }
                };

                this.moveFire = function () {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
                        particles[i].moveCirc();
                        particles[i].gravityMe();
                    }
                };

            }


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        <div id = "score_card"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```